# PostgreSQL: How to sort union query on not included column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, union, postgresql-9.5

I try to `ORDER` 2 `UNION`ed queries. Running this:

```
SELECT b.id
  FROM book.book b 
    WHERE title ILIKE '%something%' 
UNION
SELECT b.id
  FROM book.book b
    JOIN book.book_person bp
      ON bp.bookID = b.id 
    JOIN person p 
      ON p.id = bp.personID 
    WHERE lastname ILIKE '%something%' 
    ORDER BY b.title ASC, b.year DESC, b.volume ASC
```

gives me error:

```
ERROR:  42P01: missing FROM-clause entry for table "b"
LINE 12:         ORDER BY b.title ASC, b.year DESC, b.volume ASC
                          ^
LOCATION:  errorMissingRTE, parse_relation.c:3140
```

Without `ORDER`-clause it works fine. And it works fine when I include cols I want to ordered by:

```
SELECT b.id, b.title, b.year, b.volume 
  FROM book.book b 
    WHERE title ILIKE '%something%' 
UNION
SELECT b.id, b.title, b.year, b.volume 
  FROM book.book b
    JOIN book.book_person bp
      ON bp.bookID = b.id 
    JOIN person p 
      ON p.id = bp.personID 
    WHERE lastname ILIKE '%something%' 
    ORDER BY "title" ASC, "year" DESC, "volume" ASC
```

Is there better way to order `UNION`ed queris than include more columns?

Comment: eurotrash's & my answers are a bit different because i think we had different understandings of what your last query was trying to do - are you trying to have all title matches, then all last name matches in (title asc, year desc, volume asc) order, or to get all title & last name matches and then do the title/year/volume sort? (I assumed the latter)

Comment: @AdamKG: you assumed correctly, I search for 'something' inside title or person lastname and I need all book's IDs (directly from book.book or related to person) sorted by title, year and volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because first the `UNION` result is created, then the `ORDER BY` is performed. `title` etc is no longer available to be references from the `UNION` result. (Basically UNION binds more tightly than ORDER BY.)

So to get around it just put brackets around the second query and the ORDER BY statement, assuming you only want to order that part:

```
SELECT id
...
UNION
(SELECT id
...
ORDER BY title, etc)
```

If you want the full query to be ordered, your UNION'd query will have to return all the ordering columns, then you'll do a select on that:

```
SELECT id
FROM (
    SELECT id, title, etc
    ...
    UNION
    SELECT id, title, etc
) x
ORDER BY title, etc
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the correct way to do it; if you need to have only the `id` output, just wrap your existing query with a `select id from (...)_`.

The reason you need to include columns you want to sort on in your union selects is, per [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-select.html#SQL-UNION):

> `select_statement` is any SELECT statement without an ORDER BY, LIMIT, FOR NO KEY UPDATE, FOR UPDATE, FOR SHARE, or FOR KEY SHARE clause. (ORDER BY and LIMIT can be attached to a subexpression if it is enclosed in parentheses. Without parentheses, these clauses will be **taken to apply to the result of the UNION**, not to its right-hand input expression.)

So the `ORDER BY` applies only to the result of the union, which, when only the book ID is output, only has that column available. So yeah, to have both result sets sorted by those other columns, they have to be in the `SELECT` column lists of both sides of the `UNION`.

Answer (score 0):

How about getting rid of the `union` entirely?

```
SELECT b.id
FROM book.book b LEFT JOIN
     book.book_person bp
     ON bp.bookID = b.id LEFT JOIN
     person p 
     ON p.id = bp.personID 
WHERE b.title ILIKE '%something%' OR p.lastname ILIKE '%something%' 
ORDER BY "title" ASC, "year" DESC, "volume" ASC
```

Comment: This was my first approach, but then my query did not use indexes from either table, so I thought UNION way I can guarantee that indexes are used. Actual query is little bit more complicated, because ILIKE (and indexes) works on multiple columns.

Comment: @w.k . . . This should use indexes for the `join`s.  Standard (b-tree) indexes won't be used for the `like` comparisons, because the pattern starts with a wildcard.

Comment: Should it make difference, that I use on both cases gin-indexes?

Comment: @w.k . . . GIN indexes can be used for `like` and ilike`.  That makes the `union` approach more reasonable.